# Sorting files in an numerical order

Tags: cmd.exe, imagemagick

I have multiple tiff images ordered from 1 to 246. I converted them to a PDF file  using imagemagick with `convert *.tif out.pdf`. However the order of the pages inside the pdf file differs; (for example, page 2 is image 10 and so on). When I run `dir` or `ls` I get un-ordered files like the following:

```
21/06/2018  16:15    <DIR>          .
21/06/2018  16:15    <DIR>          ..
21/06/2018  15:51             2.056 1.tif
21/06/2018  15:51            98.710 10.tif
21/06/2018  15:51            96.492 100.tif
21/06/2018  15:51            44.064 101.tif
21/06/2018  15:51            70.960 102.tif
21/06/2018  15:51            85.254 103.tif
21/06/2018  15:51            92.750 104.tif
21/06/2018  15:51            87.672 105.tif
21/06/2018  15:51            90.284 106.tif
21/06/2018  15:51            79.532 107.tif
21/06/2018  15:51            85.956 108.tif
21/06/2018  15:51            22.452 109.tif
21/06/2018  15:51            91.796 11.tif
(...)
```

What i want:

```
21/06/2018  16:15    <DIR>          .
21/06/2018  16:15    <DIR>          ..
21/06/2018  15:51             2.056 1.tif
21/06/2018  15:51            98.710 2.tif
21/06/2018  15:51            96.492 3.tif
21/06/2018  15:51            44.064 4.tif
21/06/2018  15:51            70.960 5.tif
21/06/2018  15:51            85.254 6.tif
21/06/2018  15:51            92.750 7.tif
21/06/2018  15:51            87.672 8.tif
21/06/2018  15:51            90.284 9.tif
21/06/2018  15:51            98.710 10.tif
21/06/2018  15:51            91.796 11.tif
(...)
```

How can I sort the files in numerical order?

Comment: They *are* in alphabetical order. You want them in numerical order.

Comment: @TRiG Yes, how can i do that ?

Comment: Haven't a notion, as I don't use Windows. But you could [edit] your question to ask the correct question.

Comment: You need to rename files in 3 digit name. For example `1.tif` would be `001.tif`. In that case files will automatically be in order.

Comment: There is one answer, but it uses freeware: [TCC/LE](https://jpsoft.com/products/tcc-le.html) is an enhanced replacement for `cmd`. There are many enhancements, one of which is that the `dir` defaults to sorting in the order you want. I use it whenever I work on Windows, and it implements many of the features of a Linux shell, but in keeping with `cmd` syntax.

Comment: @AFH You were right, the Windows sort command does not sort as expected and my small sample subset of files I used originally was not enough so as soon as I added a `~2.txt` and a `~15.txt` it was all out of whack.... ha

Comment: Another option is to use @Sandeep's technique, but avoid post-processing by getting ImageMagick to create files starting at `101.tif`, making alphabetic and numeric sorting identical (up to `999.tif` - not a problem as you have 254 files). What command did you use to create your files?

Comment: Wait, are you telling me `explorer.exe` doesn't have the option to sort by numeric order natively **at all**?  I always thought it just wasn't one of the defaulted selections and assumed it could be found when you go to additional sort/group parameters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use following batch file to rename files to use 3 digit name. Then you can use default sorting order of windows to make your PDF file correct.

```
@echo off
setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion
for %%f in (*.tif) do (
    set FileName=%%~nf
    set FileName=00!FileName!
    set FileName=!FileName:~-3!
    set FileName=!FileName!%%~xf
    ren "%%f" "!FileName!"
)
```

On executing above batch file, file name would be changed to `001.tif, 002.tif, 020.tif... etc`. `imagemagick` will use default sort order and will generate correct PDF.

Comment: Beware numbers with leading zero are treated as octal in Batch. 010 == 8
Have a look at https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20140116-00/?p=2063

Answer (score 2):

Do you care for some powershell?   Like, eg.:

```
$D = get-childitem
$B = foreach ($F in $D) {
  "{0,30}" -f  $F.Name
}
$B | sort
```

producing:

```
PS C:\temp\test> c:\temp\numdir.ps1
                     1.txt
                     2.txt
                    10.txt
                   100.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are eight whole lines of Python code to get this done without any OS-specific scripting. I've made it to allow for a file prefix (in your case there is none so line 3 is ''). It might be fun to turn this into a fancier command-line tool, but the elementary core of the logic for the same platform-specific solutions above is more readily seen here:

```python
import os
ld = os.listdir()
i  = len('')     # if files have a prefix, set it here
m  = len(max(ld,key = len))
for f in ld:
    d = m - len(f)
    if d > 0:
         os.rename(f,f[:i] + "00000"[:d] + f[i:])
```

Where ld = list directory; i = the insertion point for any zeroes, as determined by the length of the naming prefix (in your case of no prefix it's 0, but len('test') for 'test1.tif' to 'test123.tif' would make the insertion point 4); m = length of the longest filenames in the directory; d = difference in length between the longest filename and that of the file currently being examined. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

And I also just discovered that this printf()-style escapement will cause ImageMagick to create output files in series *with* padded zeroes -- and you can presumably do other useful things with this escapement.

```
magick input*.png -resize 50% output%03d.png
```

The above ought to create output001.png, output002.png, etc. from the input file series, but note that presumably it's in the order that the OS has encounters the files. I haven't messed with it yet.

Sources:

https://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?t=32626

[Can `magick` rename output file the same as input file with additional numbering?](https://superuser.com/questions/1535588/can-magick-rename-output-file-the-same-as-input-file-with-additional-numbering)