# Can `magick` rename output file the same as input file with additional numbering?

Tags: imagemagick, file-conversion

Suppose in a folder, I have `dog.jpg` and `fish.jpg`. I want to resize them by 50% and save them with the same name, but with a numerical index. How can I do that using `magick` (allowing me to pipeline later on)? I tried the following, but it didn't seem to work:

```
magick '*.jpg' -set filename:base "%[basename]"  -resize 50% '%[filename:base]_%02d.jpg'
```

It produced `dog_%02d.jpg` and `fish_%02d.jpg` instead of `dog_01.jpg` and `fish_02.jpg` as desired.

Answer (score 2):

I combed through the documentation on [IM percent escapes](https://imagemagick.org/script/escape.php) ([see also](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/files/#save_escapes)) and [IM sequence frame numbers](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/files/#adjoin) and didn't see anything indicating this, but my experimentation seems to indicate that printf-style sequence frame number escapes (e.g. `%02d`) can only be used when the output-file argument is passed without other percent escapes:

```
[gnubeard@mothership: ~]$ convert *.jpg 'image_%02d.jpg'
[gnubeard@mothership: ~]$ ls *.jpg
dog.jpg  fish.jpg  image_00.jpg  image_01.jpg
```

vs.

```
[gnubeard@mothership: ~]$ convert '*.jpg' -set filename:f "%t"  -resize 50% '%[filename:f]_%02d.jpg'
[gnubeard@mothership: ~]$ ls *.jpg
dog_%02d.jpg.jpg  dog.jpg  fish_%02d.jpg.jpg  fish.jpg
```

This may be less than ideal because you can't control the number of digits in the filename, but here's one workaround:

```
[gnubeard@mothership: ~]$ convert '*.jpg' -set filename:f "%t_%p"  -resize 50% '%[filename:f].jpg'
[gnubeard@mothership: ~]$ ls *.jpg
dog_0.jpg  dog.jpg  fish_1.jpg  fish.jpg
```

The `%p` escape evaluates to the current sequence frame number, which might be good enough for your purposes. (Note that indexing starts from 0, and the [documented solution](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/files/#scene) if you want indexing to begin at 1 is to pass 'null:' as the first image argument and subsequently remove the resultant junk image.)

Comment: I see. That's an interesting workaround. Thanks!